# Why do singularities disappear when performing convolutions with the Dirac Delta function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, convolution, singularity

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.4**

---

I am attempting to perform a convolution involving the Dirac Delta function:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t+1} \cdot \delta(t+1)\ dt$

I would expect that the result of this integral is undefined; however, Mathematica says that it is $-1$.

Strangely, Mathematica also says that the following similar integral also evaluates to $-1$:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t} \cdot \delta(t+1)\ dt$

This makes no sense to me based on Wolfram's definition of the Dirac function, which states that:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \cdot \delta(x-a)\ dx = f(a)$

Can anyone explain Mathematica's rational to me?

Mathematica Code

```
Integrate[1/(tao + 1) * DiracDelta[tao + 1], {tao, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> ```
> -1
> ```

```
Integrate[1/(tao) * DiracDelta[tao + 1], {tao, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> ```
> -1
> ```

Screenshot
[image]

Wolfram Technical Support contacted, a support case with the identification **[CASE:3433414]** was created.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual code, not an image of it, so that readers can run the code without retyping it.

Comment: While the rule that integrating $f(t)$ against the $\delta$ function yeilds $f(0)$ applies only to suitably nice functions, I think it's a bug. It happens in general, too, to `Integrate[DiracDelta[t - a]/(t - a), {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]`, even for symbolic `a`.  The `Integrate` code translates the function $f(t) = 1/(t+a)$ to $f^*(t)=1/t$, but it does not translate the location of the singularity $t=a$ to $t = 0$; so you end up with $f^*(a) = 1/a$ for the result instead of either $0$ or an error message.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I agree it's a bug and I added the corresponding tag. The expected result can be see here: `Integrate[DiracDelta[t]/t,{t,-Infinity,Infinity}]`.

Comment: I was going to answer that you can get the expected result by doing `Integrate[DiracDelta[t-a]/(t-a),{t,-m,m}]`, but that ends up being unconvincing because I can also produce an incorrect error message with a similar command: `Integrate[DiracDelta[t-a]/(t-a),{t,2a,3a}]`. Here, the singularity is outside the integration domain, so the correct result must be zero. *Mathematica* version 10 misses this, too.

Comment: Wolfram Technical Support contacted, a support case with the identification [CASE:3433414] was created.

Comment: Just to be clear:  the second integral is correct, since it agrees with the formal definition in the case $f(x) = 1/x$ and $a = -1$.  The first one is definitely screwy, though.

Comment: Under investigation.

Answer (score 2):

With **Limit[]** seems to work.

```
 Limit[Integrate[1/(t + 1 + \[Epsilon])*
 DiracDelta[t + 1], {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}], \[Epsilon] -> 0]
```

> $\infty$

```
 Limit[Integrate[1/(t + 1 - \[Epsilon])*
 DiracDelta[t + 1], {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}], \[Epsilon] -> 0]
```

> $-\infty$

we have at the same point: $(\infty\ \text{and} -\infty) \to \text{undefined}$

Or:

```
{Limit[Integrate[
1/(t + 1 + \[Epsilon])*
DiracDelta[t + 1], {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}], \[Epsilon] -> 
0, Direction -> 1], 
Limit[Integrate[
1/(t + 1 + \[Epsilon])*
DiracDelta[t + 1], {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}], \[Epsilon] -> 
0, Direction -> -1]}
```

> $\{-\infty ,\infty \}$